# PyQT6 update radio button color every second

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I am new to PyQT and need to find a way of updating status of a service every few seconds. Currently I am using fabric2 to connect to a remote server to check status and radio buttons with background color using setStyleSheet to show service status (red/green). I was able to get it working using QTimer, I know it's not the  best way and am looking for some guidance. There are about 15 services that I need to monitor, all from the same server.

```
c = Connection('server.com', user="user", connect_kwargs={"key_filename": "c:/Users/devuser/.ssh/id_rsa",})

def check_service(service):
    global c
    result = c.run('systemctl is-active --quiet ' + service, warn=True)
    if result.exited == 0:
        color = "green"
    elif result.failed:
        color = "red"
    return(color)
```

I also have buttons that will stop/start services

```
btn_NF_stop.clicked.connect(partial(stop_service,"server-service"))
btn_NF_start.clicked.connect(partial(start_service,"server-service"))
```

The way I could make it work was to put a function outside of the MainWindow to pull service status using QTimer every 5 seconds.

```
def update_status(self):
     self.IOC_NF_status.setStyleSheet("QRadioButton::indicator {background-color : %s }" % check_service("server-service.service"))
```

...

```
    timer = QTimer(self)
    timer.timeout.connect(self.update_status)  
    timer.setInterval(5000)  # 1000ms = 1s
    timer.start()
```

But this slows down the GUI. I read about workers and threads but not sure if that's the way to go and how to implement.

Comment: I don't know what that `c` is (nor why you are using `global` for it), but I assume that you're using a library that runs a subprocess (maybe the Invoke module?). It's not really clear the need for such a library just to run a simple command and get its returned result, so I'd suggest you to clarify that point. Note that if you really just need to run a command at specific intervals, then you should probably use QProcess instead, which allows asynchronous connections to its output (preventing the UI to freeze, like your function would). Then it's just a matter of starting it with a QTimer, »

Comment: » which will eventually check if the process is not active and then start it again, and connect the QProcess `readyReadStandardError` or `readyReadStandardOutput` signals to a function that changes the stylesheet based on the output of `readAllStandardError()` or `readAllStandardOutput()`, respectively.

Comment: c is the connection to the remote server. I am using fabric2 to make a call to a remote server to check the status of a service. I am new to python so I am not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: That kind of information is fundamental to us in order to understand your problem, and without knowing it we are left to wild assumptions (like I did). I suggest you to take your time to do some research on what you're doing and then [edit] your question in order to provide all necessary details, as we cannot help you if we don't have enough context to understand your issue.

Comment: thank you. I have edited my question and hopefully that provides enough context and detail.

Comment: You should probably move the `c.run()` within a QThread subclass (possibly within a while loop that eventually sleeps for a second between each call, and with some control flag to know if it should run or wait) and a custom signal that will be emitted with the output of the command.